# How to manage IPs in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've deployed a Java application to my EC2 instance.
 It should make parallel requests to a service. 
Moreover, I need to use different IP addresses from IP pool to make requests using two different IPs to the same service. 
Is it possible to do that via Amazone EC2? 
If so, then how can I setup the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it would appear that you wish to use EC2 to test making parallel requests to a service somewhere else.

I would recommend that you launch more EC2 instances rather than attempting to attach multiple Elastic Network Interfaces each with it's own Elastic IP and make your application use them. This approach would probably be more complicated than it's worth and take longer to make work than the alternate approach of more EC2 On Demand instances.

If you are going to be doing this more than a few times, I would make a script that will take a instance with it's base AMI through to fully configured and automatic execution of the tests you want to run. This way you can just paste this data into the UserData field of the EC2 Launch wizard.

An even better solution would be to create an Autoscaling Group with a launch configuration that has your UserData script specified. That way you can scale up or down instances at the click of a button rather than manually deploying them each time. When your tests are not in use you can set the min, max and desired number of instances values in your Autoscaling Group to 0 effectively ending the test deployment.

**Here is some further reading that may assist you:**

*UserData for Ec2 Instances*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

*Autoscaling Groups*

https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/

*Launch Configurations*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/LaunchConfiguration.html

**Some information to help you with the multiple ENI/EIP approach:**

*Attaching additional ENIs to an EC2 instance*

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/multiple-ip-addresses-for-ec2-instances-in-a-virtual-private-cloud/

*ENI Documentation*

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html